# Show a list in ToString override method

Tags: c#, tostring

I was wondering if it's possible to show a List inside the `public override string ToString()` method, so when I list all the properties I also can see each element of a `List<>` there.

This is my `ToString()` method:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.Employees; //Here would be the list
}
```

And this would be the constructor for Employees with the properties that I wish to list. 
For example: Employee: John Doe, Employee: Brian Johnson, Employee: Eric Dunn.

```
public Employee(string fullname)
{
   this.FullName = fullname;
}
```

Comment: `string.Join` is your friend, if you want to use the `ToString()` defined on the objects in the list.  If not, then a `StringBuilder` and a loop.

Comment: How the class looks like? The `override string ToString()` belongs to the Class `Employee` or some other class that contains `List<Employee>`

Comment: @BenVoigt can you give an example of how would you put together the `ToString()` method adding `string.Join`?

Comment: If you are looking for something that will generically pull out the name of the class and its contents, you might want to consider converting your list to its JSON representation, eg with the NewtonSoft JSON nuget's Serialise().
(Edited: i mistakenly said Deserialise in an earlier version of this comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to override `ToString` as below:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join(",", this.Employees
                                .Select(employee => $"Employee: {employee.FullName}"));
}
```

Comment: this works showing me all the properties of the class, but does not concatenate several employees.

Comment: @hendrix oops...my bad...I just corrected it. Thanks !

Comment: Seems that I was creating the list incorrectly and that is why your code was not working. Thank you so much, I was completely stuck.

Answer (score 2):

```
public override string ToString()
{
   StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(Employee e in this.Employees)
   t.AppendLine (string.Format ("Employee: {0}",e.Fullname));
   return t.ToString ();
}
```

Or

```
public override string ToString ()
{
  return String.Join ("Employee: ", this.Employees.Select (e => e.Fullname).ToArray<string>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, the following classes with override .ToString() will solve your issue. Here I'm using two classes one with Employee details and another with List of first classes

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpCode { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Employee Code : {0} \n Employee Full Name : {1}", this.EmpCode, this.FullName);
    }
}

public class EmployList
{
    public List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in EmployeeList)
        {
            strBuilder.AppendLine(item.ToString());
        }

        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

**How to use the Above classes**

```
EmployList listObject = new EmployList();
listObject.EmployeeList.Add(new Employee(){EmpCode=1,FullName="suji"});
listObject.EmployeeList.Add(new Employee(){EmpCode=11,FullName="jon"});
listObject.EmployeeList.Add(new Employee(){EmpCode=12,FullName="anu"});
listObject.EmployeeList.Add(new Employee(){EmpCode=13,FullName="achu"});

Console.WriteLine(listObject.ToString());
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O67PEs)

Comment: do you have a simpler solution? i'm not all that experienced in object oriented programming and this is part of a bigger project and I want to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: Sure, I can help you with simpler example if you add clear details about your requirements with the question